# How to read Javascript object from the server before the page is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My page works with directives that interface to an object ' invoice ' defined only on the server.

I want to know what is the best way to stop the rendering of the page to complete loading the object , in order to avoid error ' undefined ' of object properties..

```
     angular.module("adocApp")
      .controller("ctrl",
         function ($scope, $http ) {


            $scope.loadingIsDone = false; //variable that stop rendering of page


        $http.get("Home/init").success(function (data) {
            $scope.invoice = data;
            $scope.loadingIsDone = true; //this start rendering with ng-if... but seems bad solution
                   });


    });
```

Comment: resolve you can try.
before loading route, use resolve to get data from some service then it will only render page after resolve promise is over.
https://thinkster.io/egghead/resolve

Comment: where are you seeing `undefined`? Update question with actual errors

Comment: $http get asynchronous request... then if in my directives I have some:

       <input ng-model="invoice.qty">
or

        <li ng-repeat="prd in invoice.listOfProducts">

qty and listOfProducts does not exist at the moment of render.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the HTML in your view with `DIV` element and display it only after you have fetched the invoice from the server

```
<div ng-if="invoice">
    .... your directive here ......
</div>
```

And of course you can show the directive the same way using `ng-if` (without having to wrap it)

Comment: Great!!
But this let me to avoid the use of 'loadingIsDone' variable and its logic.

It Works, but the question is: "Is that the better way to implement the logic of read the resources from server?"

My case is one single page application that, in future, will work with other objects (other than 'invoice').

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: @treep No, you should resolve the object and inject it to the controller ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)). More details [HERE](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)